# How to render the image or several images in the table render element?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I have a form. In the last step of the form, I display in the table what was saved in the fields in the previous steps.

Where there is a comment in the code, I need to render the all images from the `$taxonomy_pms_color` that was saved in the previous steps.

```
$quote_printing_pms_colors = $quote_print_location->get('field_pms_colors')->getValue();
$pms_colors = '';

foreach ($quote_printing_pms_colors as $pms_color_value) {
  $taxonomy_pms_color_target_id = $pms_color_value['target_id'];
  $taxonomy_pms_color = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($taxonomy_pms_color_target_id);
  $image_uri = $taxonomy_pms_color->get('field_image')->entity->getFileUri();
}

$print_locations_rows[] = [
  'pms_colors' => [
    'data' => [
      //Here should be the rendered images
    ],
  ],
];

}

if (!empty($print_locations_rows)) {
  $print_locations_header = [
    'col1' => $this->t('PMS Colors'),
  ];

  $form['confirm_quote']['designs_and_finishing_wrapper']['design_wrapper'][$key]['print_location_table'] = [
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $print_locations_header,
    '#rows' => $print_locations_rows,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['my-class'],
    ],
  ];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I have several images I can render the images like this:

```
$rednered_image = [];

$rednered_image[] = [
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#uri' => $image_uri,
  '#style_name' => 'thumbnail',
];
```

I can pass the images to the `<td>` of the table as follows:

```
'thread_colors' => [
  'data' => [
    'images' => $rednered_image,
  ],
],
```

The updated code will look like this:

```
$quote_printing_pms_colors = $quote_print_location->get('field_pms_colors')->getValue();
$pms_colors_name = '';
$rednered_image = [];

foreach ($quote_printing_pms_colors as $pms_color_value) {
  $taxonomy_pms_color_target_id = $pms_color_value['target_id'];
  $taxonomy_pms_color = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($taxonomy_pms_color_target_id);

  $taxonomy_pms_color_name = $taxonomy_pms_color->getName();
  $pms_colors_name .= '<span>' . $taxonomy_pms_color_name . ' ' . '</span>';

  if ($taxonomy_pms_color->get('field_image')->entity) {
    $image_uri = $taxonomy_pms_color->get('field_image')->entity->getFileUri();
    $rednered_image[] = [
      '#theme' => 'image_style',
      '#uri' => $image_uri,
      '#style_name' => 'thumbnail',
    ];
  }

}

$print_locations_rows[] = [
  'thread_colors' => [
    'data' => [
      'images' => $rednered_image,
    ],
  ],
];

if (!empty($print_locations_rows)) {
  $print_locations_header = [
    'col1' => $this->t('PMS Colors'),
  ];

  $form['confirm_quote']['designs_and_finishing_wrapper']['design_wrapper'][$key]['print_location_table'] = [
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $print_locations_header,
    '#rows' => $print_locations_rows,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['my-class'],
    ],
  ];
  
}
```